# How to stop opening popup or 3rd party link except main link in android webview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-webview

Hey guys I'm new to coding. And I've made a blog. Now with help of online tutorials I'm able to create android webview app in Android studio. But issue is my blog has popups, so those same popups open on app as well, which is annoying as the back button and 50% of popups hangs app.

Is there any way to disable those external links except my original domain link on app? Anyway we can define to not open external domain links.

Pls help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the Javascript execution in the WebView by setting it as false before calling the loadUrl() method.

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSetting = view.getSettings();
view.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
view.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
```

Comment: Hi I tried that code, but i am getting an error. of "cannot be referenced from a static context"